# barcode ending in line-break intermittent

Tags: php, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm currently building an application that will be making use of barcodes, but the scans are behaving a little strangely and sometimes ending in a line break and sometimes not, so 4 scans of *ABC123* might scan into

ABC123

ABC123ABC123

ABC123

Any ideas how to make it consistent at all? I can't find anything about it online and it's proving to be more of a pain than i'd hoped.

Symbology used is Code39

Edit: should add that ideally it will end in a carriage return every time

Comment: `trim()` each scan and add line ending if necessary?

Comment: it would work in a sense but what I want it to do is automatically submit a form once the scan is carried out, hence the desire for the carriage return. It always gets the content itself just fine, just sometimes has to be submitted manually